# How to add a custom header to HttpClient()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, custom-headers

I'm trying to add a custom header to the request header of my web application. In my web application I'm retrieving data from a web API, in this request I want to add a custom header which contains the string `sessionID`. I'm looking for a general solution so that I don't have to add the same code before every call I make.

My Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> getCall()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:51080/";
        string customerApi = "customer/1";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //get logged in userID
            HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            string sessionID = context.Session["userID"].ToString();

            //Create request and add headers
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Custom header


            //Response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(customerApi);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsondata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return Content(jsondata, "application/json");
            }
            return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Hope anybody can help!

Comment: Which header name would that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Version","1");`

Comment: When I try this and I run the application and use inspector tool -> network and i view the headers it does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Collection behind `DefaultRequestHeaders` has Add method which allows you to add whatever header you need:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("headerName", sesssionID);
```

Comment: When I try this and I run the application and use inspector tool -> network and i view the headers it does not appear.